# Can I use same docker container with spark after 10 years?

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, machine-learning, kubernetes

Can we use the same docker container with Spark after 10 years?

I am wondering to find some limitations on what will happen if today I am running preparing docker container (Kubernetes) with Spark for advanced machine learning and if I can use the same after 10 years to reproduce the same results?

For example:

1. Can I use the same versions for Kubernetes/docker/spark/python/MLcode after 10 years?
2. Is it an underlying OS that will support running these containers with the same configuration in the future?

I would like to decide if keeping container-based strategy to reproduce the same results after 10 years will help or I only need to keep the data and create a new program after 10 years to try to reproduce the same results?

Comment: Are you still using all the technologies now which are from 10 years ago without any updates?

Comment: Yes, some of them with legacy systems. The objective is to reproduce the same results after 10 years.

Answer (score 1):

Incredibly unlikely but barring a message from the future no one can say for sure. Containers aren't a small interface like VMs were/are. They touch the whole of the kernel interface and that changes over time. Sometimes rapidly. Not to mention that container tech itself changes rapidly, image formats, executable formats. Hell, if we aren't all running on ARM CPUs in 10 years I'll be kind of annoyed with our industry, that alone will require rebuilding or emulating everything in the world :D

Comment: Thank you CodeRanger for the explanation and yes, this makes sense. I have to EDIT the question because StackOverflow had marked it as an opinion-based question.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the best strategy in your case is to keep both the OS image of the VM with docker installed, and the docker image with spark or other programms whose results you'd like to reproduce in the future, all inside that VM image. It's likely that you'll be able to run an old VM image in on a modern system of the future.

Another answer said that an older image may not be possible to use to create a container in the future due to container middleware versions. Docker may not even be around in 10 years.

Another thing to consider - you'll have difficulties building an image from Docker file too - due to luck of all necessary dependencies in the repos in the future.

But having a VM image with all the stuff you need will likely to lead to success. If VM image format changes, there will be converters. VM engine, be so kvm or virtualbox or a new one, will likely have an emulator for that old vm, just like they have many emulators for different systems, including those no longer in use.

Comment: Thank you Artem for the explanation and yes, this makes sense. I have to EDIT the question because StackOverflow had marked it as an opinion-based question.